# How to do implicitly convert to a class that has methods of the same name

Tags: scala

Say I define the following class with an implicit conversion:

```
abstract class Holder[K, V] {
    var map = Map[K, V]()
    def key(v: V): K
    def get(v: V) = map.get(key(v))
}

implicit def toMap[K, V](holder: Holder[K, V]): Map[K, V] = holder.map
```

And I try to use it thus:

```
val holder = new Holder[Long, String] {
    def key(str: String) = str.toLong
}

holder.get("3")
toMap(holder).get(3)
holder.get(3)
```

Compilation will fail on the last line as the implicit conversion cannot be resolved. I am guessing this is because the class Holder already contains the method get(). Is there a way I can achieve implicit conversion to a class with same named methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could "force" an implicit conversion, or make it a bit more explicit, with something like this:

```
implicit class ImplicitApplicator[A](a: A) {
  def as[B](implicit conv: A => B): B = conv(a)
}
```

Then you could do:

```
holder.as[Map[Long, String]].get(3)
```

Otherwise, I don't think there's any way around the name conflict. That's one of the fundamental limitations of implicit conversions.